# Why does my volunteering with kids mean I should get a tetanus shot?

Tags: vaccination, infection, infectious-diseases, tetanus-shot

I volunteer with kids a decent amount.  A little while ago my doctor recommended that I get the tetanus shot specifically due to the fact that I spend so much time around small children.

At the time I didn't think to ask, but now I'm wondering why is the amount of time I spend around children relevant to my risk of tetanus?

Comment: Ask yourself what else comes with the tetanus vaccine and then write your own answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory, the use of combined Tdap vaccines is not universal.  There are parts of the world where you can get a straight tetanus booster shot.  If you're suggesting that the doctor is indirectly hinting that the OP should get a pertussis booster, you should say so.

Comment: @Mark That would be answering in a comment. Just trying to point him in the right direction for finding the answer.